# Directive to end LTSpice simulation

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and LTSpice to explore the design space of a circuit. The netlist is specified using Python and LTSpice is ran in the background to solve it.
I need to run LTSpice more than 1000 times and the simulations take several hours. However, for most of the cases, I know that if certain conditions are achieved the simulation can be stopped and the simulation time can be decreased significantly. LTSpice only allows a fix Stop simulation.

I would want to know if there is any LTSpice directive that allows stopping the simulation something like:

.MEAS TRAN STOP_SIMULATION  STOP_SIMULATION WHEN V(x)>0.5

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code which you have tried (do not provide a link, but rather provide actual code snippets) - that will make it much easier for people to provide a useful and timely response.